# Graphs: Recognizing a $P_4$ subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, planar-graphs

I'm trying to build an algorithm that says if a graph is *trivially perfect* or not. I realized that I can look if a graph is $(C_4, P_4)$-free as they are equivalent. (https://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_343.html)

I managed to create an algorithm to recognize $C_4$ subgraphs by reading *Recognition of $C_4$-free and $\frac 1 2$-hyperbolic graphs* from David Coudert and Guillaume Ducoffe.

But I can't find any clue of how to make this $P_4$ recognition. Does anyone know how can I find a pseudo-code or any information that might help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: By $P_4$ do you mean the path with $4$ edges, or the path with $4$ vertices?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Path with 4 vertices. This kind of graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connected graph has no induced $P_4$ subgraphs if it has diameter at most $2$. One way to check this is to compute the square of the adjacency matrix, and verify that it has no zeroes.

This can be done in $O(n^\omega)$ time, where $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication exponent. Even if there's something more clever to be done, this is already faster than checking for induced $C_4$ subgraphs by the method in the paper you cite, so it's not going to be the bottleneck.

If the graph is not connected, we can find the connected components (in $O(n^2)$ time) and handle each of them separately.

---

Alternatively: when the vertices $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are sorted from highest to lowest degree, the graph is trivially perfect if for every edge $v_i v_j$ with $i<j$, $N(v_i)$ contains $N(v_j)$.

This gives (at the very least) an $O(n^\omega)$ algorithm for your original problem. After sorting in this way, let $A$ be the upper triangular half of the adjacency matrix. Then the graph is trivially perfect if $A^2$ has no positive entries anywhere that $A$ has zero entries.

Possibly we can do even better.

Comment: So, if the square of the adjacency matrix does not have zeros, it is P4-free?

Comment: Thank you for this definition on Trivially Perfect graphs, it will help a lot!

Comment: For a connected graph - if the graph is not connected, you'll still have zeroes between the connected components.

Comment: But if I multiply the adjacency matrix, and I realize that it has a P4 in it. How do I know with vertex make this P4?

Comment: If there's an unwanted $0$ in position $(i,j)$, then you know vertices $i$ and $j$ are endpoints of *some* $P_4$, though maybe not the same one. You want to find two vertices at distance $3$; for that, you should also compute the cube of the adjacency matrix, and find a nonzero entry there that had a zero in the square.